# I am getting an error message when trying to split a string and put them into an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, split, strtok

I am trying to split the user's input and put each delimiter in an array.

For some reasons, with the code I have here, I get an error message:

> called object type 'char *[10]' is not a function or function pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define SIZE 256

char *read_line(char *buf, size_t sz) {
  printf("> ");
  fgets(buf, sz, stdin);
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
  return buf;
}

void split(char *buf, char *split[], size_t max) {
  char *temp = strtok(buf, " ");

  for (int i = 0; split[0] != '\0'; i++) {
    strcpy(split[i], temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, buf);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *buf = malloc(SIZE);
  char *split[MAX];

  while(1) {
    char *input = read_line(buf, SIZE);
    split(input, split, MAX);
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You name a variable and a function `split`. Rename your buffer to something other than `split` and it should compile. https://godbolt.org/z/t2dx4Y

Comment: Error messages refer to specific line numbers.  What ***line*** is this error on?

Comment: '30:10: error: called object type 'char *[10]' is not a function or function pointer
    split(input, split, MAX);' -  it is my code, but I can only ask a question every 90 minutes.

Comment: It works now. @Zaiborg noticed my mistake. It just got past me.

Comment: @JakeJackson Why should you run into the question limit? You should ask one question, and *edit* it to provide the requested information. Please don't ask multiple questions about the same error, and *please* don't create multiple accounts!

Answer (score 2):

This declaration in the scope of the outer block of main

```
char *split[MAX];
```

hides the function with the same name declared in the file scope.

Rename the array as for example

```
char *words[MAX];
```

The function `split` is invalid at least because you are trying to copy strings in a non-allocated memory

```
strcpy(split[i], temp);
```

The function can look the following way

```
size_t split( char *buf, char *words[], size_t max ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    char *temp;

    if ( n < max && ( temp = strtok( buf, " \t" ) ) != NULL )
    {
        do
        {
            words[n] = temp;
        } while ( ++n < max && ( temp = strtok( NULL, " \t" ) ) != NULL );
    }

    return n;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
int main( void ) 
{
    char *buf = malloc( SIZE );
    char *words[MAX];

    size_t n = split( read_line( buf, SIZE), words, MAX );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( words[i] );

    free( buf );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define SIZE 256

char * read_line( char *buf, size_t sz ) 
{
    printf("> ");
    fgets(buf, sz, stdin);
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;

    return buf;
}

size_t split( char *buf, char *words[], size_t max ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    char *temp;

    if ( n < max && ( temp = strtok( buf, " \t" ) ) != NULL )
    {
        do
        {
            words[n] = temp;
        } while ( ++n < max && ( temp = strtok( NULL, " \t" ) ) != NULL );
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *buf = malloc( SIZE );
    char *words[MAX];

    size_t n = split( read_line( buf, SIZE), words, MAX );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( words[i] );

    free( buf );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
> Hello kindawg
Hello
kindawg
```